# Why does the Redux.js "Dispatch" TypeScript interface have a template parameter?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

[Relevant line](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts#L96).

If the interface is as follows:

```
export interface Dispatch<S> {
    <A extends Action>(action: A): A;
}
```

...and `S` is clearly not used, then why is it there?

I notice that `S` is used elsewhere for "store" related things, but if it's not used in this interface, I don't think it should be there.

Comment: You can see the pull request that added that interface and the reasoning on this link: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1537

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having state type parameter S allows middlewares be more accurate in
>   typings. For example, thunk function takes a dispatch and a
>   getState(): S, so without S it couldn't be well-typed. See the example
>   of this here below
>   https://github.com/Igorbek/redux/blob/ts-def-improv/test/typescript/dispatch.ts#L9-L16

[Source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/1537#r57173994)

Credit goes to @Lucas for finding that source.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, on it's own it does not appear to make much sense.

My guess is they have done it to ensure like dispatch functions are returned in [middleware](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts#L271).

In the case of a middleware like redux-thunk, the [new dispatch function](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/index.d.ts#L8) does use the `<S>` parameter, although I'm not sure it would matter if the default one did not in this case.